# Fixing elements in a permutation

Tags: combinatorics, functions, permutations

Let $f= (1 4 6)(2 7 5 8 10)(3 9)$. Specify an integer $n$ such that $f^n$ fixes exactly seven elements of the set $\{1,2,...,10\}$.

I computed $f$, $f^2$, $f^3$ etc, hoping I could find the integer $n$, but this got tedious. Is there a more simple way?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You can show that for an integer $k$ $f^{2k}$ fixes the numbers $3$ and $9$, $f^{3k}$ fixes the numbers $1,4,6$, and $f^{5k}$ fixes the numbers $2,7,5,8$ and $10$.

This of course means that $f^{6}$ fixes **five** numbers, $1,4,6$ and $3,9$ because $6$ is divisible by both $3$ and $2$.

Now, can you find a value $n$ such that $f^{n}$ fixes seven numbers? (Another hint, $7=5+2$)

Comment: Would f^10 fix seven numbers?

Comment: @Zain It might, yeah! Can you provide a good argument for that?

Comment: Not very good with starting off arguments. Can you provide any insight please?

Comment: @Zain You should explain which numbers you think are fixed, and which are not. And you should explain **why** they are fixed and **why** they are not.